# How to get the result of adb shell command in Embarcadero Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, adb

I need to get the list of packages of my Android device using Embarcadero Delphi XE10 Seattle

```
procedure TDeviceInfoForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var   stdout:JOutputStream;
      stdin:JInputStream;
      suProcess:JProcess;
begin  
      suProcess:=TJRuntime.JavaClass.getRuntime.exec(StringToJString('pm   list     packages'));
      stdout:=suProcess.getoutputStream;
     stdin:=suProcess.getInputStream;
end;
```

Comment: And the problem is...? You have a stream for the process's `stdout`, simply read from that stream and then parse what you read. But why are you using ADB for this task at all?  You should be using Android's [`PackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) class instead, which has a [`getInstalledPackages()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages(int)) method. Use Delphi's `SharedActivity.getPackageManager()` method to retrieve a pointer to a `JPackageManager` interface.

Comment: I just need to know how to parse process stream and extract packages

Comment: Again, you should not be using ADB for that at all. Use `PackageManager` instead. Its `getInstalledPackages()` method returns a `List` of `PackageInfo` objects. Simply loop through that list directly.

Comment: I already done that and my question is how to parse and read stdout and stdin in the code above using delphi

Comment: You are asking a different question. First you asked how to get a list of packages, now you are asking how to read from stdout. Two different questions.

Comment: If you read the `Process` documentation, its `getInputStream()` method returns an `InputStream` for stdout. `InputStream` has overloaded `read()` methods for reading bytes. You can read the content of stdout directly into your own byte buffer. A better approach is to wrap the `InputStream` inside of an `InputStreamReader` object and then wrap that inside of a `BufferedReader` object, then you can call the reader's `readLine()` method to read individual lines as strings from the stdout stream.

Comment: But WHY go to this trouble? ADB is the wrong solution to your problem. Why don't you want to use the `PackageManager` directly? ADB simply delegates to `PackageManager` internally, so cut out the middle man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going about this the wrong way.  You should not be using ADB at all.  Use Android's [`PackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) class instead.  Its [`getInstalledPackages()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages(int)) method returns a `List` of [`PackageInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) objects, one for each package.  Simply loop through that list, eg:

```
uses
  ...,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.Helpers;

procedure TDeviceInfoForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  list: JList;
  iter: JIterator;
  pkg: JPackageInfo;
begin  
  // read the getInstalledPackages() documentation for details about the available flags...
  list := TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);
  iter := list.iterator;
  while iter.hasNext do
  begin
    pkg := TJPackageInfo.Wrap((iter.next as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
    // use pkg as needed...
  end;
end;
```